# Generate set of Nouns and verbs from n different descriptions, list out descriptions that match a noun and verb

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, nltk

Im new to NLP, i have with columns app name and its description. Data looks like this
app1, description1 (some information of app1, how it works)
app2, description2
.
.
app(n), description(n)
From these descriptions i need to generate a limited set of nouns and verbs. In the final application, when we pair a noun and verb from this list, output should be of list of apps that satisfy that noun+verb.
I dont have any idea where to start, can you please guide me where to start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The task of finding the morpho-syntactic category of words in a sentence is called part-of-speech (or PoS) tagging.
In your case, you probably need also to tokenize your text first.

To do so, you can use [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features), or the [Stanford NLP tagger](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) (among other tools).

Note that depending on the model you use, there can be several labels for nouns (singular nouns, plural nouns, proper nouns) and verbs (depending on the tense and person).

Example with NLTK:

```
import nltk

description = "This description describes apps with words."
tokenized_description = nltk.word_tokenize(description)
tagged_description = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_description)
#tagged_description:
# [('This', 'DT'), ('description', 'NN'), ('describes', 'VBZ'), ('apps', 'RP'), ('with', 'IN'), ('words', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]

# map the tags to a smaller set of tags
universal_tags_description = [(word, nltk.map_tag("wsj", "universal", tag)) for word, tag in tagged_description]  
# universal_tags_description:
# [('This', 'DET'), ('description', 'NOUN'), ('describes', 'VERB'), ('apps', 'PRT'), ('with', 'ADP'), ('words', 'NOUN'), ('.', '.')]
filtered = [(word, tag) for word, tag in universal_tags_description if tag in {'NOUN', 'VERB'}]
# filtered: 
# [('description', 'NOUN'), ('describes', 'VERB'), ('words', 'NOUN')]
```